# Why does python interpret '\12' as '\n'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that contains the following sequence in it `'10\S\12/L'`

I want to split the string based on lines using `.split('\n')` however it causes the string to break on the `'\12'`. I found whenever a string contains this the interpreter prints the string with a line break.

Why is `'\12'` the same as `'\n'` and how can i prevent it?

Comment: As the applicable documentation tells you, a backslash (escape signal) followed by an octal number has a special meaning.  What do you not understand from the docs?

Comment: @Prune IMO, that is a particularly dense and hard-to-google-in-the-first-place section of the Python documentation.

Comment: Note that unless you truly, positively know all escape sequences by heart, it is a good idea to use raw string literals for any string that is supposed to contain several literal ``\``. It is probably already a good idea even if there is just one literal ``\`` in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Python is interpreting that as the [octal code for a newline](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), led off by that backslash escape and followed by 12.

You can see that in reverse:

```
>>> # Python 3.9 REPL
>>> oct(ord('\n'))
'0o12'
```

See the Python docs on [String and Bytes Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

"`\ooo` denotes the *[unicode] character with octal value ooo* ... accepting *up to* 3 digits," but in this case, stops at those two.

If you want to include a *literal backslash* in your string, you can either:

- escape it with another backslash: `'\\12'`
- use a *raw* string literal prefixed with "r": `r'\12'`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned from comments, Python interprets the 12 as *n* as because 12 is its ASCII code. You have two ways of fixing this.

1. Add "r" to the beginning of the string.

```
string = r"10\S\12/L"
```

2. Escape each slash you want included in your string. So if you want "\12" literally, use:

```
string = "10\S\\12/L"
```